Associating a "global" default value for GraphQL arguments
I'm not sure that "global" default value is the best term for this. Maybe "default default" ?  In any case, here's the problem:
For queries that return collections, I want to define a PagingOptions argument like so:
public class PagingOptions {
   public  int start = 0;
   public int limit = 100;
   public SortOptions sort = null;
}

A query might look like:
 public Page<UserType> getUsers(@GraphQLArgument StandardCollectionArgs options)
The default values for the PagingOptions fields are stated in the class declaration. How would I declare this as the default value for the options argument in the query?  I could use @GraphQLArgument(defaultValue="JSON representation of the PagingOptions"), but I'd have to repeat that everywhere I include a PagingOptions argument. Same goes for defaultValueProvider.
Is there any why to associate a default value with a class used as a GraphQLArgument?

I don't have a computer at hand right now, so I'll post a proper answer tomorrow, but in short: this is doable via a custom default value provider ( but there are other means if necessary). But tell me one thing, are you using this with Spring or with something else? Because there is built-in support for Spring's paging mechanism.

Thanks @kaqqao. No, I'm not using this with Spring. After I thought about this a bit more, it became obvious that I don't really need a GraphQLArgument-like annotation at all. I really just need to define an input type that looks like my PagingOptions class. Please let me know if I'm wrong about this.

Although, in looking at this more closely, using an input type doesn't quite work because it doesn't provide a mechanism to declare a default value. This is not a bit deal, because I can obviously add some code to each resolver to set the argument to a default if it's null. So, I'd still be interested in your recommendation on more elegant solutions using a custom default value provider or other.
